Why component still re-render even with the same state value?
I have the code snippet as follows,
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);

  return (
    <>
      {console.log("rendered...", state)}
      <button onClick={() => setState(1)}> Change </button>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;

Here is the output:
launch: rendered...0
first click: rendered...1
second click: rendered...1
third click: (no output)
code not run in strict mode.
why the second time of clicking, component still re-rendered even if an identical value is provided, and why the third time react could finally skip re-render?

You can find answer here: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/20817 or here: https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update

If you update a State Hook to the same value as the current state, React will bail out without rendering the children or firing effects. (React uses the Object.is comparison algorithm.)


Note that React may still need to render that specific component again before bailing out. That shouldn’t be a concern because React won’t unnecessarily go “deeper” into the tree. If you’re doing expensive calculations while rendering, you can optimize them with useMemo.

That's why your component will render 1 more time with the same result
